# Syntax error from copy to clipboard command = unable to copy Text and template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day.

I've been trying top figure out why the copy to clipboard not working despite of putting the correct form name, please advise what would be the best command, i've been trying so hard couldn't seem to make it work.

here is the sample of the form or template im working on 
I was hoping to use the copy to clipboard function so i can copy the title and content of each line

```
if (window.event.srcElement == frm.copyform){
                frm.holdtext.value = Template;
                Copied=frm.holdtext.createTextRange();
                Copied.execCommand('copy');
                alert('Copied to Clipboard!');
            }
```

---

```
       

<script>
<script> }
    if (window.event.srcElement == frm.copyform){
     frm.holdtext.value = Template;
     Copied=frm.holdtext.createTextRange();
     Copied.execCommand('copy');
     alert('Copied to Clipboard!');
    }
   }
  </SCRIPT>
<head>
<body>
<!--Special comment-->
<!--Style-->
<style type="text/css"> 
/* Some Generic styles */
H1 {
    Color: #9c33ff;
    font-size: 20px;
    isplay: inline-block;
}

H2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    Color: #751aff;
    font-size: 13px;
}


Body {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 580px;
  height: 800px;
  border: none;
  font: normal 12px/1 "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(2,2,2,1);
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(153,103,206,1) 0, rgba(247,221,200,0.57) 49%, rgba(140,226,226,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(153,103,206,1) 0, rgba(247,221,200,0.57) 49%, rgba(140,226,226,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(153,103,206,1) 0, rgba(247,221,200,0.57) 49%, rgba(140,226,226,1) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
  background-size: auto auto;
}
    label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: Left;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
}
TBODY {
    font-size: 14px;
    Color: #313133;
    font-size: 13px;
}    
    
#tickettemplate {
    font-size: 15px;
    Color: #313133;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>

<!--Html starting point-->

<h1>i</h1>
<h2>i</h2>

<P align=center><IMG 
src="" alt="" width="80" height="83"></P>
<FORM name=tickettemplate id=tickettemplate>

<!-- Table to contain page title and buttons -->
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD align=center colSpan=4>
      <DIV></DIV></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD><INPUT name=Reset onclick="resetForm();return false;" type=reset value="Clear All Fields"> 
    </TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=copyform onclick="val1();return false;" type=button value="Copy to Clipboard"> 
    </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><!-- Table for General information --><BR>

<!--This is where i started-->

<TABLE 
style="FONT-SIZE: 13pt; BORDER-TOP: gray solid; BORDER-RIGHT: gray solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: gray solid; BORDER-LEFT: gray solid" 
14pt? FONT-SIZE:><STRONG>General Info</STRONG></TD></TR> 
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Name:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=cname_singleuser id=cname_singleuser size=50> 
</TD>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>User ID:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=userid_singleuser0 id=userid_singleuser0 size=50> </TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top>Callback no.: </TD>
    <TD><INPUT name="callback no" id=callbackno0 size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Email Address:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=emailaddy_singleuser id=emailaddy_singleuser 
size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Office Location</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=oloc_singleuser id=oloc_singleuser 
size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Current Location:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=cloc_singleuser id=cloc_singleuser 
size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD vAlign=middle>Exisitng/Related:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=exrelated_singleuser id=exrelated_singleuser 
    size=50></TD></TR>
    <TD vAlign=top>Business Unit/Client:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=client1 id=client1 size=50> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR>
<TABLE width=750 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
  <TBODY>

<TABLE 
style="FONT-SIZE: 13pt; BORDER-TOP: gray solid; BORDER-RIGHT: gray solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: gray solid; BORDER-LEFT: gray solid" 
14pt? FONT-SIZE:><STRONG>Brief Description</STRONG></TD></TR> 
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Issue: </TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=Issue id=issue0 size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top>Number of Users Affected: </TD>
    <TD><INPUT name="Number of users Affected" id=numberofusers0 
size=50></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top>Business Impact:</TD>
    <TD><SELECT name="Business Impact" id=businessimpact0 size=1 type="text"> 
        <OPTION value="" selected></OPTION> <OPTION value=Minor>P4 
        Minor</OPTION> <OPTION value=Medium>P3 Medium</OPTION> <OPTION 
        value=High>P2 High</OPTION> <OPTION value=Major>P1 
      Major</OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD width=400 vAlign=top><p>Additional information/
      Incident Description:</p></TD>
    <TD><TEXTAREA name=Description id=Description1 rows=8 cols=60 wrap=virtual></TEXTAREA></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width=750>
  <TBODY>
  <TR><BR><STRONG>Choose the Category:</STRONG></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: where did you get that form? Seems a bit odd.

Comment: Hi i tried to use jfiddle then i got the syntax error, tried multiple times to check but i am unable to figure it out, 

im still trying to learn java, so new to it. learning from the internet. my apologies.

Comment: You are not learning Java, you are learning JavaScript. Two totally different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got that code from, but seems to be wrong. If you are copying the text from an input it is pretty straight forward. Focus, select, and copy from a click action.

```js
function copy(event) {
  var selector = event.target.getAttribute('data-copy')
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector)
  elem.focus()
  elem.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}

document.querySelectorAll('[data-copy]').forEach( function () {
  this.addEventListener('click', copy)
})
```

```html
<textarea id="foo">Hello world</textarea>
<button type="button" id="btnCopy1" data-copy="#foo">copy</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="bar">Hello world</textarea>
<button type="button" id="btnCopy2" data-copy="#bar">copy</button>
```

Comment: my apologies again, question though will that work for multiple input but only on one copy button, super grateful for your help

Comment: So you change the ta line to use a reference instead of a hardcoded value.

Comment: function copy() {
var ta = document.getElementById('cname_singleuser')
var te = document.getElementById('userid_singleuser0')
var ti = document.getElementById('emailaddy_singleuser')
  ta.focus()
  ta.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
   te.focus()
  te.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
   ti.focus()
  ti.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}

document.getElementById('btnCopy').addEventListener("click", copy)

Comment: I updated it to use a data attribute which is how I would have it copy different elements.

Comment: If you are trying to copy multiple things to the clipboard at once, well this is NOT how it is going to work.

Comment: i tried to put a form name like <FORM name=tickettemplate id=tickettemplate> followed by stuff like this <TR>
    <TD vAlign=middle>Name:</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name=cname_singleuser id=cname_singleuser size=50> 
</TD>  is there a way to get javascript copy the texts? i appreciate all the help and knowledge i can get.

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 8

i am getting this error im not so sure why but i will try this